# How do I access a resource file in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode7

To access the resource file `namefile` from a program:

[image: main.cpp]

I ostensibly just need to check the box "target membership" to identify it as a resource file:

[image: target membership]

but this box is disabled.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `helloworld` target in your project is configured as a command-line tool (the square black icon that looks like a Terminal indicates this).  Those compile to a single, standalone file thus Xcode cannot embed a resource file with it (which is why it's disabled).

You need to build a "Cocoa Application" target if you want to be able to include resource files.  You can start a new project using the Cocoa Application template or manually add a target to your current project. You'll probably find it easier to start with a new project.

Comment: That makes it very clear. So unlike, for example, QtCreator, a "resource" does not just get translated to a header file to be embedded (as if it were an icon). If you know of a way to handle stdin (http://stackoverflow.com/q/41096878/704972), please also answer that question.

Comment: Correct. It's impractical for large applications to embed hundreds or thousands of resource files thus MacOS X apps (other than small command-line tools) are compiled as [bundles](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

#### Add resource files to a command line tool

---

Add the file to the "Copy Files" section of your project's Build Phases:

[image: Build Phases screen]

Make sure to set `Destination` to "Resources", clear `Subpath`, and untick `Copy only when installing`.

Then whenever you build, Xcode will copy the file into your app's build directory, right next to the executable:

[image: Xcode build folder]

That's a screenshot of the `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[your project]/Build/Products/Debug` folder.

This method also works when you archive your app.

---

Note: if you want the file to be in some subfolder relative to the executable, e.g. `res/images/`, set the `Subpath` to that path.